# Angular Breeze input box type="email"

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I recently added breeze into my angular project because of a change in requirements.  I choose breeze because I wanted to get the metadata from the web api which I am using with entity framework.  However once I got breeze configured, loaded the metadata from the webapi, and bound my newly created models to my input boxes on my forms I ran into a problem.  I am using an input with the type="email" attribute and I can no longer type in that input!

I forked a project from Ward Bell on Plunker and changed the input type on the email address to "email" and I cannot type in that input either.

[MyPlunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/IpBsTLYHdnU50pLbanyR)

Am I missing something?  Or is this designed behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found two bugs, but as for right now I just do not have the time to work on investigating any further.  I just need a solution so I can move on.

So this is what I found.  When I fetchMetadata from my ***breeze/metadata*** web api, I get:

> {\"name\":\"EmailAddress\",\"type\":\"Edm.String\",\"maxLength\":\"30\",\"fixedLength\":\"false\",\"unicode\":\"true\",\"nullable\":\"false\"}

I've made sure the the attribute on my property in my model for EmailAddress is `[EmailAddress]` (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations), but it seems the EFContextProvider isn't looking at this attribute correctly.  This is where I think one bug is located.  I am not sure if this project is Open Source or not, but if it is I will look into when I get time or if someone out there already knows, I would be grateful to learn if it is a bug or I just did something wrong.

So after I get the metadata, I then go to create my first entity in the entity manager and if I look at the validators for my property EmailAddress, it only has two validators, required and maxlength.  So I hooked up the EmailAddress validator.

```
var emailProperty = newEmployee.entityType.getProperty("emailAddress");
emailProperty.validators.push(breeze.Validator.emailAddress());
```

The second bug I believe is when I use the `data-z-validate` attribute with the `<input type="email"/>` going this renders the input box unusable.  Which is the problem I had with the original question.  So to make it work, I am just letting breeze validate my email address and it is working fine.

Comment: If Breeze does the validation, can you remove the `type="email"` and keep the z-validate? Is that better or worse than ditching the z-validate and keeping the type?  P.S.: I do want to get to the bottom of this; just haven't had time.

Comment: I've removed the 'type="email' from my input and I am letting z-validate, validate my email address.  I did this because I was able to push the 'breeze.Validator.emailAddress()' in to my emailProperty.  Better or worse, I don't know, I just brought Breeze into my application because of a requirement change.  Prior to Breeze I was just using json objects in an angularjs service, but I needed something more robust.

Comment: Another advantage of the zValidate approach is that you can customize and extend the property validation logic (beyond what `Validator.emailAddress` give you) without changing your HTML markup.

Comment: I can verify the exact same is happening to me - type="email" worked w/my jscript model and throws away the keystrokes when I replaced it with breeze.